# How to write Unit test cases for Linq joins for Get API in DotNet

Tags: linq, unit-testing, join

```
public LoginUserDTO GetUserDetailsById(int id)
{
        var result = _loginRepository.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false && x.Id == id)
                    .Join(_loginStatusRepository.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false),
                    login => login.LoginStatusId,
                    loginStatus => loginStatus.Id,
                    (login, loginStatus) => new { login, loginStatus })

                    .Join(_loginHasRoleRepository.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false),
                    loginAndloginStatus => loginAndloginStatus.login.Id,
                    loginHasRole => loginHasRole.LoginId,
                     (loginAndloginStatus, loginHasRole) => new { loginAndloginStatus, loginHasRole })

                     

                     .Join(_loginHasPhoneRepository.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false),
                     loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole => loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginAndloginStatus.login.Id,
                     loginhasphone => loginhasphone.LoginId,
                      (loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole, loginhasphone) => new { loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole, loginhasphone })

                     

                     .Select(x => new LoginUserDTO()
                     {
                         LoginFirstName = x.loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginAndloginStatus.login.LoginFirstName,
                         LoginLastName = x.loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginAndloginStatus.login.LoginLastName,
                         LoginEmail = x.loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginAndloginStatus.login.LoginEmail,
                         LoginStatusName = x.loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginAndloginStatus.loginStatus.LoginStatusName,
                         RoleName = x.loginAndloginStatusAndloginHasRoleAndrole.loginHasRole.Role.RoleName,

                         AllowSms = x.loginhasphone.Phone.AllowSms,
                         PhoneNumber = x.loginhasphone.Phone.PhoneNumber,
                     }).FirstOrDefault();

        return result;

    }
```

The method returns the users details using UserId , I was getting error when I was mocking the repositories using setup , was not able to join the repositories

```
using Capstone2.DTO.Models;
using Capstone2.Entities;
using Capstone2.Entities.Entities;
using Capstone2.Repository.Interfaces;
using Capstone2.Service.Services;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Capstone2_API_Tests.Services
{
\[TestFixture\]
public class LoginServiceTest
{
protected Mock\<ILoginRepository\> \_mockLoginRepository;
protected Mock\<ILoginHasPhoneRepository\> \_mockLoginHasPhoneRepository;
protected Mock\<ILoginHasRoleRepository\> \_mockLoginHasRoleRepository;
protected Mock\<ILoginStatusRepository\> \_mockLoginStatusRepository;
protected Mock\<IPhoneRepository\> \_mockPhoneRepository;
protected Mock\<IRoleRepository\> \_mockRoleRepository;
protected Mock\<IPhoneTypeRepository\> \_mockPhoneTypeRepository;
protected LoginService \_loginService = null;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _mockLoginRepository = new Mock<ILoginRepository>();
            _mockLoginHasPhoneRepository = new Mock<ILoginHasPhoneRepository>();
            _mockLoginHasRoleRepository = new Mock<ILoginHasRoleRepository>();
            _mockLoginStatusRepository = new Mock<ILoginStatusRepository>();
            _mockPhoneRepository = new Mock<IPhoneRepository>();
            _mockRoleRepository = new Mock<IRoleRepository>();
            _mockPhoneTypeRepository = new Mock<IPhoneTypeRepository>();
    
            _loginService = new LoginService(_mockLoginRepository.Object,
                _mockLoginHasPhoneRepository.Object,
                _mockLoginHasRoleRepository.Object,
                _mockLoginStatusRepository.Object,
                _mockPhoneRepository.Object,
                _mockRoleRepository.Object,
                _mockPhoneTypeRepository.Object);
    
    
    
    
          _mockLoginRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false && x.Id == 1)).Returns(
           
              new List<Login> { new Login()
                {
                   Id = 1,
                  LoginFirstName = "Aman",
                  LoginLastName = "Singh",
                LoginEmail = "amansingh71130@gmail.com",
                Password = "9d6PamEkXI1eOjz6BTHMU8E4qmVwKk0yBwSI/AJzYws=",
                LoginStatusId = 1,
                FailedLoginAttempts = 4,
                IsLocked = false,
                RegistrationStatus = true,
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
    
    
               } }.AsQueryable());
    
            _mockLoginHasPhoneRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false)).Returns(
                new List<LoginHasPhone> { new LoginHasPhone()
                {
                Id = 1,
                LoginId = 1,
                PhoneId = 1,
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            }}.AsQueryable());
    
           
            _mockLoginHasRoleRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false)).Returns(
                new List<LoginHasRole> { new LoginHasRole()
            {
                Id = 1,
                RoleId = 1,
                LoginId = 1,
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            } }.AsQueryable());
    
    
    
    
           
    
            _mockLoginStatusRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false)).Returns(
                new List<LoginStatus> { new LoginStatus()
    
                 {
                Id = 1,
                LoginStatusName = "Active",
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            } }.AsQueryable());
    
           
    
            _mockPhoneRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false)).Returns(
                  new List<Phone> { new Phone()
                   {
                Id = 1,
                PhoneNumber = "1234",
                PhoneTypeId = 1,
                AllowSms = true,
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            }}.AsQueryable());
    
    
            
            _mockRoleRepository.Setup(m => m.FindByQueryable(x => x.DeleteFlag == false)).Returns(
           new List<Role> { new Role()
            {    Id = 1,
                 RoleName ="Admin",
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            }}.AsQueryable());
    
            PhoneType phoneType = new PhoneType()
            {   Id = 1,
                PhoneTypeDesc = "12",
                CreatedBy = 1,
                CreatedDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow,
                DeleteFlag = false,
            };
    
            _mockPhoneTypeRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(1)).Returns(phoneType);
    
            
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            
        }
    
       
      
    
        [Test]
        public void GetUserById_Successful()
        {
    
          
            
            //Act
            int Id = 1;
           var result = _loginService.GetUserDetailsById(Id);
    
            //Assert
          
            Assert.Pass();
    
        }
    
      
    }

}

tried this way, But I was getting Null in result.
```

Comment: Please turn this into a [mre], with an emphasis on "minimal".

Comment: That said, as a side note, it looks like you should use [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) here; *and* navigation properties instead of these verbose and tiring joins.